# on windows8 where can I find info when was some application started

Tags: windows-8, process

I want to know when a certain application started.
I tried searching in TaskManager > Processes > Properties, but couldn't find it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if Task Manager can, but you can get the information from [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Just right click on the process and click properties.

[image]

Comment: It's a very nice tool.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it and it is working fine. Do you know if this information is available in `WMIC process list` (or any other `WMIC` feature)?